# SQL to calculate Net Capacity

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a SQL to get the Net change in capacity by using the capacity (when status is  1 or 2) and minus the total capacity (when status is 3) for each month? Thanks. Here is the table:

```
STATUS        MONTH    CAPACITY     
1                01/16     5        
3                01/16     2        
1                02/16     11       
3                02/16     20       
1                03/16      8       
3                03/16     12       
1                04/16      4       
2                04/16     10       
3                04/16     18       
2                05/16     14       
3                05/16     37       
2                06/16      4       
3                06/16      8
```

For example, the net change in capacity for Jan. 16 is 5 minus 2 equals 3.

Answer (score 5):

You need a conditional sum:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (1,2) THEN CAPACITY ELSE 0 END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (3)   THEN CAPACITY ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 2):

dnoeth answer can be simplified to

`SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (1,2) THEN CAPACITY WHEN STATUS IN (3) THEN -CAPACITY ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 1):

Builds on 1,2 < 3

```
select MONTH, [Net change]=SUM(CASE STATUS/3 WHEN 0 THEN CAPACITY ELSE -CAPACITY END)
from t
group by MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself and perform the calculation like so:

```
SELECT
   a.status,
   a.month,
   a.capacity,
   b.capacity AS total_capacity,
   a.capacity - b.capacity AS net_capacity
FROM
   table a
JOIN
   table b
   ON (a.month = b.month)
   AND (b.status = 3)
WHERE
   a.status IN (1,2);
```

-- If you don't want to have the status and instead aggregate in the event there are two within the same month:

```
SELECT
   a.month,
   SUM(a.capacity) AS capacity,
   SUM(b.capacity) AS total_capacity,
   SUM(a.capacity) - MAX(b.capacity) AS net_capacity
FROM
   table a
JOIN
   table b
   ON (a.month = b.month)
   AND (b.status = 3)
WHERE
   a.status IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
   a.month;
```

Comment: Assumes only two rows per month. Won't work on month `04/16` in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

no `CASE` statement:

```
select month, sum(capacity)-2*sum((status/3)*capacity) from table group by month;
```

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/CWHP36071)

Comment: This is clever mathematically etc, but I think possibly really confusing for the OP without further explanation.  Some of the other solutions are at least more obvious as to how they work.

Comment: @MatRichardson I was working on the writeup after I posted the answer.

Comment: Even so...I personally think whilst your solution is clever it's way too complex (despite its apparent 'simplicity').  This is the kind of thing you'd post on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, but not here.  Look at the higher scoring answers and ask why they have been voted.

Comment: @MatRichardson http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319970/are-complex-answers-a-bad-thing

Comment: I appreciate answers like this - if it is correct and an alternative way to do it. +1

Comment: Fair point and I apologise if any offence caused - just thought the solution could be much simpler is all.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  "Status",
  "Month",
  SUM(Capacity) AS Capacity
FROM ( SELECT
         "Status",
         "Month",
         CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN -1 * Capacity ELSE Capacity END AS Capacity FROM tbl
     ) t
GROUP BY
  "Status",
  "Month"
```